# Auto populating value hide if I click on the input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, typeahead, twitter-typeahead

I have 3 input fields in my form and these are Country, State and City. I am using Typeahead in Country input field to populate country.

Typeahead display data as following-

US - DC

US - MD

UK - London

If I choose "US - DC" then in Country field I display "US" and in State field "DC".

Here, the problem is- then if I click on Country input field then it replace the value "US" with value "US - DC". And if I click on State input field it remove the value "DC" from the field.

I am using following code-

```
$("#country-id").bind("change", function(e){
    var country = $(this).val();

    var t = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: './state',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'id='+country,
        cache: false,
        dataType:'json',

        success: function(data) {
            if(data.state != "")
                $("#state-id").val(data.state);

            var countryVal = country.split("-",1);
            console.log(countryVal);
            t.val(countryVal);
        }
    })  
});
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap typeahead 3 ?

Comment: Yes, I am using Bootstarp Typeahead. I am using by following http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/typeahead